# QT can't build - "Some of the required modules (!win32-g++) are not available"

Tags: qt, mingw

I pulled down the qtpdf repository to check out and play with from here:

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/qtpdf.git

As soon as I open the qtpdf.pro file, I get the following general messages:

```
Cannot read C:/.../build-qpdf-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/src/lib/pdfium.pri: No such file or directory
Cannot read C:/.../build-qpdf-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/src/lib/freetype.pri: No such file or directory
Project MESSAGE: perl -w C:\Qt\5.10.0\mingw53_32\bin\syncqt.pl -module QtPdf -version 5.9.0 -outdir "C:/.../build-qpdf-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug" C:/.../qtpdf
Project MESSAGE: perl -w C:\Qt\5.10.0\mingw53_32\bin\syncqt.pl -module QtPdfWidgets -version 5.9.0 -outdir "C:/.../build-qpdf-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug" C:/.../qtpdf
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: pdfwidgets
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: pdf
```

Also when running "rebuild all" I get the following error message:

```
16:15:33: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" qmake_all
"Some of the required modules (!qnx:!uikit:!winphone:!winrt:!win32-g++:!integrity) are not available."
"Skipped."
```

I've narrowed this down to !win32-g++ - If I remove that, it won't throw that error, but I don't understand what exactly this error means - I have googled around a lot but couldn't find anything that seemed reminiscent of this particular problem.

Comment: It basically means that you don't have a Windows version of G++ (Typically the MinGW compiler). That's the best I can tell from what you provided. I can also add that something is wrong with how the PRO files are linked together, as it seems like the `pdf` and `pdfwidgets` modules (from the same-named subfolders), are not properly detected

Answer (score 1):

I managed to build qtpdf with mingw provided with Qt5.11.2.

1. Comment out "requires(!qnx:!uikit:!winphone:!winrt:!win32-g++:!integrity)" from pdf.pro
2. Apply the patch found here : https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-pdfium-git/pdfium-2729.patch (link dead in 2021, no backup sorry)
3. Add -luuid after "win32: LIBS_PRIVATE += -ladvapi32 -lgdi32 -luser32" in lib.pro
4. I don't know why, probably because I am not an expert, but mingw doesn't generate correctly the folder "include". As a workaround I use the one generated under linux. For some reason, mingw generate only QPdfDepends and QPdfWidgetsDepends, none of the needed headers are generated. I didn't dig because I am lazy.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I managed to build with Qt 5.9.1 and also `VPATH += $$QTPDF_ROOT/src/3rdparty/pdfium/third_party/freetype/include` is needed to add to qtpdf\src\lib\lib.pro.
To use new modules (e.g. pdfwidgets) in your project, include `*.pri` files from qtpdf\mkspecs\modules into your `pro` file.

Answer (score 0):

> # Upstream PDFium has not been ported to various platforms yet.
>   requires(!qnx:!uikit:!winphone:!winrt:!win32-g++:!integrity)

The module is not working on `win32-g++ (mingw32)`.